# custom dynamic toast in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, toast

Making in react native customised dynamic toast,

**first :**
I just want to Simply **put my button code and message will allow me to utilise my toast on any page**, however the code below keeps everything on one page. **How can I modify this so I can use it everywhere?**

**second :** **when I click first time** on button **want to toast a single toast** as usual but **when I clicked on multiple** times on button t**he Toast Message should appear as per clicks**.
below image for reference [image]

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import Toast from './_path_/Toast';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Toast />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**Toast.js**

```
  import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      Animated,
      Button,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Dimensions,
    } from "react-native";
    import { AntDesign, Entypo } from "@expo/vector-icons";
    
    const Toast = () => {
      const windowHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
      const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
      const popAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(windowHeight * -1)).current;
      const successColor = "#6dcf81";
      const successHeader = "Success!";
      const successMessage = "You pressed the success button";
      const failColor = "#bf6060";
      const failHeader = "Failed!";
      const failMessage = "You pressed the fail button";
    
      const popIn = () => {
        Animated.timing(popAnim, {
          toValue: windowHeight * 0.35 * -1,
          duration: 300,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start(popOut());
      };
    
      const popOut = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          Animated.timing(popAnim, {
            toValue: windowHeight * -1,
            duration: 300,
            useNativeDriver: true,
          }).start();
        }, 10000);
      };
    
      const instantPopOut = () => {
        Animated.timing(popAnim, {
          toValue: windowHeight * -1,
          duration: 150,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
      };
    
      return (
        <View>
          <Animated.View
            style={[
              styles.toastContainer,
              {
                transform: [{ translateY: popAnim }],
              },
            ]}
          >
            <View style={styles.toastRow}>
              <AntDesign
                name={status === "success" ? "checkcircleo" : "closecircleo"}
                size={24}
                color={status === "success" ? successColor : failColor}
              />
              <View style={styles.toastText}>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 15 }}>
                  {status === "success" ? successHeader : failHeader}
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>
                  {status === "success" ? successMessage : failMessage}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={instantPopOut}>
                <Entypo name="cross" size={24} color="black" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </Animated.View>
    
          <Button
            title="Success Message"
            onPress={() => {
              setStatus("success");
              popIn();
            }}
            style={{ marginTop: 30 }}
          ></Button>
    
          <Button
            title="Fail Message"
            onPress={() => {
              setStatus("fail");
              popIn();
            }}
            style={{ marginTop: 30 }}
          ></Button>
    
        </View>
      );
    };
    export default Toast;
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      toastContainer: {
        height: 60,
        width: 350,
        backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderRadius: 10,
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 0,
          height: 2,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 3.84,
        elevation: 5,
      },
      toastRow: {
        width: "90%",
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
      },
      toastText: {
        width: "70%",
        padding: 2,
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at this library:
https://github.com/backpackapp-io/react-native-toast/

It lets us to add the `Toast` component on root of the app and simply use it from everywhere.

https://github.com/backpackapp-io/react-native-toast#cool-now-what

Comment: I'm looking for in .js

Comment: This is a javascript library. I don't get what do you mean

Comment: there is also typescript.

Comment: Why does it matter? You can use typscript libraries even if you don't use it on your main application